# Does the pattern [_|_] in Erlang mean anything specific?

Tags: erlang

I am learning Erlang from [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/) and I've seen the pattern `[_|_]` twice already but couldn't find any info on it. This usage seems superfluous because omitting it from (1) and subsituting it with _ in (2) yields the same result without degrading readability. It is my first week with Erlang so I may be completely wrong.

(1) from [bestest_qsort](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/static/erlang/recursive.erl):

```
bestest_qsort(L=[_|_]) ->
    bestest_qsort(L, []).
```

(2) from [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/static/erlang/calc.erl):

```
  error:{badmatch,[_|_]} -> ok
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pattern `[p1 | p2]` matches a non-empty list, whose head matches the pattern `p1` and whose tail matches the pattern `p2`. So since the pattern `_` matches anything, `[_ | _]` matches any non-empty list.

`_` by itself on the other hand matches anything, including the empty list.

Comment: @toraritte Try `F([2,3])`. The pattern `[p]` matches a list containing exactly one element, which matches `p`. It does not match lists with more than one element (otherwise, say, `[1,2]` would match the pattern `[1]`, which makes no sense - `[1] = [1,2]` should clearly not match).